# How to make absolute redirect in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

From my custom module in Drupal 7 I want to make the redirect.

So, inside a function, I have:

```
$my_calculated_path = $base_url . '/dashboard/test/deliveries;
drupal_goto($my_calculated_path);
```

If I print the variable `$my_calculated_path` I have the full url:

```
www.mydomain.com/dashboard/test/deliveries
```

and it is correct.

The problem is the `drupal_goto($my_calculated_path)` trigger the hook menu:

```
/dashboard/test
```

and not the menu:

```
/dashboard/test/deliveries
```

What is the problem?

Comment: See: [What API function do I use for redirecting to external URLs?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/49679/1908) at Drupal SE

Answer (score 2):

Use 'external' option for external redirections:

```
drupal_goto($url, array('external' => TRUE));
```

See: [`drupal_goto()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) and [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7)

Answer (score 1):

Normally `drupal_goto()` does not allow absolute paths because this could represent a vulnerability.

Try it this way:

```
drupal_goto('dashboard/test/deliveries/', drupal_get_destination());
```

The `drupal_get_destination()` function will create the proper URL for you.

Hope this helps.